# Capybara/selenium browser refreshed with the blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

After adding selenium-webdriver gem, when started capybara test, browser started to show home page and after it, refreshed with the blank page.

It cause to fail my tests that previously passed. Showing `Capybara::ElementNotFound` error.

I use **capybara 2.2.1**; **selenium 2.42.0**; **ruby 2.1.0**; **rails 4.1.0**; **rspec 3.0**

Here is my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Navigation" do

    it "changing active menu element depending on route", js: true do

    visit '/'


    first(:link, 'WHAT IS DREAMDO?').click
    expect(find('.navigation').find('.active').find('a').text).to eq('WHAT IS DREAMDO?')

    first(:link, 'DISCOVER DREAMS').click
    expect(find('.navigation').find('.active').find('a').text).to eq('DISCOVER DREAMS')

    first(:link, 'DREAMDO WEEKLY').click
    expect(find('.dreamdo-menu-items').find('.active').find('a').text).to eq('Dreamdo Weekly')

    end

end
describe "Search", js: true do

    it "checks for the availability and search results" do
      search_text = find(:xpath, '//input[@id="search_text"]').set("chocolate")
      search_text.native.send_keys :return
      page.should have_content "chocolate"
    end

end
```

Could you, please, recommend me what to do?

Comment: What version of selenium, capybara, and rspec are you using?

Comment: @Xerif917 I use capybara 2.2.1; selenium 2.42.0; ruby 2.1.0; rails 4.1.0; rspec 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not good to use selenium, because it can't run multiple instances: 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/capybara-webkit

Try to use capybara-webkit, hope it will solve your problem.